# Can we connect to multiple Elasticsearch clusters with a single client instance in a spring boot application

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a Java Application which fetches data from elasticsearch cluster with the help of the rest high level client provided by the elasticsearch. The cluster connection and the data fetching is working perfectly but I have a situation now. Previously my cluster used to connect to a single cluster but now I have another cluster from which I want to fetch the data. The index from which the data is fetched has the same name and type of data received in both clusters is also identical.
So my question is that can we have multiple cluster connection with a single client?
And if a single client is able to connect to multiple clusters and if a request is fired using that client then 2 identical requests should be made to 2 clusters then what about the response recieved can we gather 2 response and merge it into a single response or only a single response will be received??